# When does stage get loaded?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm building a project in Adobe Flash Professional CS5 (using ActionScript 3.0).

In one of the classes, I want to add some objects to the scene based on the size of the scene.

I'm using the following code in the constructor:

```
stageWidthint = stage.stageWidth;
stageHeightint = stage.stageHeight;
startMenu.x = stageWidthint / 2;
startMenu.y = ((stageHeightint / 2) - 40);
instructionsMenu.x = stageWidthint / 2;
instructionsMenu.y = ((stageHeightint / 2) + 2);
highscoreMenu.x = stageWidthint / 2;
highscoreMenu.y = ((stageHeightint / 2) + 44);
quitMenu.x = stageWidthint / 2;
quitMenu.y = ((stageHeightint / 2) + 86);
this.addChild(startMenu);
this.addChild(instructionsMenu);
this.addChild(highscoreMenu);
this.addChild(quitMenu);
```

I'm getting a null reference on `stage`. After a quick search I found out `stage` is not yet loaded at that time. Still, I'd like to add those childs to the class. When does the stage get loaded? How can I solve this problem and still show all the stuff when the game starts?

Comment: Ok thanks, that solved my problem. I placed all those things in the method called by the event handler. But still, when is the stage done loading? is that a matter of seconds or anything?

Comment: Downvoter, care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ADDED_TO_STAGE event in your constructor.

```
 public function ConstructorName():void 
 {
     addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAddedToStage); 
 }

 private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void 
 {   
      removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAddedToStage);
      // add init code here
 }
```

Comment: Do you know when the stage is done loading? What kind of things are executed before the stage is actually loaded but after the code started running?

Comment: The stage is done loading as soon as your main class receives the ADDED_TO_STAGE, I don't really know the internals of the flash player and what it does before that. But you don't really need that knowledge, just beware that the stage member will be null for display objects that are not on the stage and before they receive the ADDED_TO_STAGE event.

Comment: Ok I got it. I hoped to pump out some performance by splitting my constructors up, but nobody seems to know what can be done in the one or other. Seems like I'll have to find it  through trial and error ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how things work when using scenes, but you could try:

```
package  {
  import flash.display.*;
  import flash.events.*;


  public class Test extends MovieClip {


    public function Test() {
      if (stage) {
        init();
      } else {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
      }
    }

    protected function init(event:Event = null):void {
      trace("init");
      if (event) { removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init) };
      //your code here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Stage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html) object is not globally available.
A class that extends a MovieClip will have a property "stage"(lowercase)
The "stage" property is null until the instance of your class has been added to stage.
That is why we listen for the ADD_TO_STAGE event.

There are work-arounds to stage = null one of which would be to pass in the stage as a parameter in the constructor IE: var xxx:MyClass = new MyClass(stage);
That is if the class creating the instance already has a reference to stage.

I would like to add that accessing stage in your custom class is not a good OOP practice since classes should be only concerned with themselves . What I would suggest is overriding the width setter/getters. This is because sizing can change for example landscape to portrait rotation.